# php unique/group associative array

Tags: php

I would like to remove duplicates for the following array. I want to group by the first value and then rebuild the index.

ie

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => California
            [state_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => California
            [state_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => New Mexico
            [state_id] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Washington
            [state_id] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Montana
            [state_id] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => Montana
            [state_id] => 4
        )
)
```

To

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => California
            [state_id] => 1
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => New Mexico
        [state_id] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Washington
        [state_id] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [title] => Montana
        [state_id] => 4
    )

)
```

and rebuild key

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => California
            [state_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => New Mexico
            [state_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Washington
            [state_id] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Montana
            [state_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: `array_unique`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @Joseph I have to take my earlier comment back. `Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.` *All* arrays are equal to `array_unique`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = array_values(array_combine(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['title']; }, $array), $array));
```

I.e.

- extract the `title` key (`array_map`)
- use the extracted titles as keys for a new array and combine it with the old one (`array_combine`), which de-duplicates the array (keys have to be unique)
- run the result through `array_values`, which discards the keys

Broken down:

```
$keys    = array_map(function ($i) { return $i['title']; }, $array);
$deduped = array_combine($keys, $array);
$result  = array_values($deduped);
```

For PHP 5.2- you'll need to write the anonymous callback function like this:

```
array_map(create_function('$i', 'return $i["title"];'), $array)
```

Comment: Nice! Did you mean `return $i['title'];` (not `echo $i['title'];`) ? ;)

Comment: array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays. I get this error on your second solution 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in

Comment: @mad It's worth noting that's PHP 5.3 syntax. You'll need to rewrite this using `create_function` in PHP 5.2-.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort your array by title (usort does the trick)
2. create a new empty array
3. Cycle original array and store the value you find in the new empty array
4. If next array value equals last then skip it

At the end of this you have the array you want.
There is another way:

1. Sort your array by title
2. Cycle original array
3. If this array value equals last then unset it
4. Sort the array again with PHP sort function to rebuild keys

Answer (score 0):

$array = [`array_unique($array)`](http://php.net/array_unique);

Yes, it works with multi-dimentional arrays too; it just checks to equality.